# Find $F''$, where $F(x)= \int_0^{2x}\tan(t^2)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let

$$F(x)= \int_0^{2x}\tan(t^2)dt.$$

I need to find $F''(1)$. Really stuck on how to do this one.

Comment: To find the second derivative you have to find the first derivative first. Can you find that?

Comment: $$F'(x)=2\tan(x^2)$$
just because derivative undone the integral
then
$$F''(x)=4 x \sec ^2\left(x^2\right)$$

Comment: Well no, I'm just starting off in calculus. I know that you must find the first derivative and then find the derivative of that, I just do not know how to go about it at first. @JohnMa

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you @NikolayGromov

Comment: Do you know the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: @NikolayGromov: why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Because there is 2 min limit per answer on stackexchange :)

Comment: @NikolayGromov I think you are missing a factor. It should be $F'(x) = 2\tan(4x^2)$.

Comment: yes you are right, sorry

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Use [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)  for differentiation under the integral with variable limits:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left( 
\int_{a\left(x\right)}^{b\left(x\right)} f\big(x,t\big)\, dt  \right)
= f\big(x,b\left(x\right)\big) \cdot b'\left(x\right)
- f\big(x,b\left(x\right)\big) \cdot a'\left(x\right)
+ \int_{a\left(x\right)}^{b\left(x\right)} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\,f\left(x,t\right)\, dt 
$$

---

In this specific case we have
$\,
f\left(x,t\right) = \tan t^2, \  a\left(x\right) \equiv 0, \  b\left(x\right) =2x, \,
$
and therefore
\begin{alignat}{3}
F\left(x\right) = \int_0^{2x}\tan t^2 \,dt
& \implies
F'  && = \frac{d}{dx} \Big( F\left(x\right) \Big) 
&& = \tan \left( 4x^2 \right)\cdot 2 - \tan 0 \cdot 0 + \int_0^{2x} 0\, \,dt
 = 
2 \tan \left( 4x^2 \right)
\\
& \implies 
F'' && = \frac{d}{dx} \Big( F'\left(x\right) \Big) 
&& = \frac{d}{dx} \Big(2 \tan \left( 4x^2 \right) \Big)  
= \ldots
\end{alignat}

Hope you can finish by yourself.